# mysql - error with creating temporary table from resultset

Tags: mysql

i want to create a temporary table on the fly from a result set so that i can run some queries against this resultset.

Here is my sql:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table_1 AS (SELECT * FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id WHERE B.id IS null);


SELECT QUA.id, QUA.name, QUA.address, QUA.acc, QUA.module, QUA.tag
FROM QUA,temp_table_1
WHERE 
QUA.name = temp_table_1.name AND 
QUA.acc = temp_table_1.acc AND
QUA.tag = temp_table_1.tag
```

When i run the first query to create the temp table, I get the error message:

'Duplicate Colum Name 'id''

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting both columns `A.id` and `B.id` without aliases to differentiate them.  Be specific about the columns you select:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table_1 AS (
  SELECT 
    A.id AS aid
    A.othercol AS a_othercol,
    B.id AS bid,
    B.othercol AS b_othercol
  FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id WHERE B.id IS null);
```

It's unwise to use `SELECT *` because you can't always guarantee the order that the columns will return in, if something changed in the original `CREATE TABLE` statement, for example.  Also, as you've discovered here, similarly named columns will cause problems in many circumstances.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these details

Answer (score 2):

THat's because you do `SELECT *`. The resultset contains all columns from both tables, so if both of them have a column called 'id' it wil be duplicated.